# Adding Foreign Key to Java DB

Tags: java, netbeans

How to add **foreign key** in **Java DB** ?

Comment: ok and the question is what?

Comment: There is no question out there, so why a question mark at the end?

Comment: Only you can answer that question. Are you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how you ALTER a table in MySQL:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/alter-table.html

You don't say which database you connect to using JDBC.

You just need to `executeUpdate()` on the table in question.  I wouldn't use Java to do it; just use the admin tool.

Comment: thanks for your reply. it would be great help